# Custom Code execution before session timeout in SAP Hybris

Tags: session, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement where I need to fetch the customer `cartModel` and send it to an API before/after the session expires for that customer. I tried using the `DefaultSessionCloseStrategy` and `closeSessionInHttpSession` methods but inside my custom class the cart is already getting expired and I’m getting null when checked using `cartService.hasSessionCart()`.
Is there any other approach to use?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the cartModel from the cartService.getSessionCart() . I just added
JaloSession jalo = JaloSession.getCurrentSession(); before calling any session related lines of code and I started getting the current session user in my debug.